# git add/stat extremely slow on RHEL

Tags: git, rhel

We have a large (~15 GB, ~40K files) and old (~5 years with daily updates) git repository full of media content.

Recently the RHEL users started to complaint it takes a few minutes to perform such routine operations like add, stat and push. At the same time on Ubuntu we don't encounter any problem.

We had a similar issue a year ago. That time the cause was that a few very large (>500 MB each) files were added but now it's not the case.

One note that may be important: RHEL users use an old RHEL 6 with official packages only.

Could you advise how to beat the issue described?

Answer (score 0):

Pending the implementation of **[GVFS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Git_Virtual_File_System)** on Linux/Unix platform (for now it is only fir Windows and soon for MacOS), you should consider [Git LFS](https://git-lfs.github.com/): that would allow you to externalize the storage of the large element in a different referential.

Then those Git operation would be faster.

In both instances, that supposes the remote hosting server used for pushing your repo does support LFS (or later GFS).

If not, the only solution would be to remove from the history the largest elements, with [Git BFG-REpo Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/) for instance.

Comment: Many thanks, will try to drop the history (unfortunately, other approaches are not immediately applicable for us as will require a major redesign of the underlying software). It'll take a while as business processes are rather slow and complicated, will write upon completion if it helps.